# Speeding up a dynamic SQL query which uses WHERE IN to filter

Tags: performance, t-sql, join

Consider the following data tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonId int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE PersonData 
(
    PersonId int, -- with foreign key to person table
    DateKey Date,
    Fact1 int,
)
```

I can perform a query like this, which will aggregate Fact1, grouped by DateKey

```
SELECT DateKey, SUM(Fact1) 
FROM PersonData
GROUP BY DateKey
```

Now let's suppose I want to filter by personId and show data for persons with id of 1 2 and 3.   I can do this:

```
SELECT DateKey, SUM(Fact1) 
FROM PersonData
WHERE PersonId IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY DateKey
```

Where this falls apart, is if I have large numbers of personIds with which I want to filter on.  i.e. WHERE T2.PersonId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 1000+)

How can I improve the performance given large numbers of PersonId to filter on?

**Update**

While the above example is a simplification of my data structure, hopefully it is an accurate analogy.

Example queries and time impacts, given approximately 32 million rows of PersonData and 2000 unique persons:

- Filtering on a single PersonId: 100ms
- No filter at all: 750 ms
- Filtering on 1500 PersonIds: **2300 ms**

Note: For all queries, I am also performing a WHERE clause to limit DateKey (foreign key to date dimension table) to a 1 month timespan.

Comment: I assume you can't express the `T2.PersonId`-space as a query of some kind? Meaning it _must_ be a  list of `Ids`?

Comment: The join on `Person` that you say improves performance looks redundant assuming that `Person -> PersonData` is one to many. What do the plans look like? What indexes on your tables?

Comment: @jonnyGold - it doesn't *have* to be a list of Ids, however it would take heavy refactoring of the application to be able to express the filter in terms of joins rather than a resultant set of ids.  I'm looking for a quick-fix here.

Comment: @MartinSmith Correct, it's one to many.  Not sure why it speeds up performance.  This example is a gross simplification of what I think the problem is.  Hopefully it is representative...

Comment: @MartinSmith After additional testing, you are correct.  There doesn't seem to be a difference with the join.  I've removed that information from my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @beginValue int = 1,
        @endValue int = 87;

--Only work if you need a interval of numbers (example: 1 to 87, in Person table)
SELECT pdt.DateKey, SUM(pdt.Fact1)
FROM PersonData AS pdt
     INNER JOIN Person AS per ON pdt.PersonId = per.PersonId
WHERE per.PersonId BETWEEN @beginValue AND @endValue
GROUP BY pdt.DateKey;
```

Comment: This is fast, but not useful.   Typically, the values will not be sequential

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading all the PersonIDs into a table in SQL.  Then use:

```
SELECT DateKey, SUM(Fact1) 
FROM PersonData D
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 from PersonIDTable I where d.PersonID = I.PersonID)
GROUP BY DateKey
```

This usually makes the query run much faster!

Comment: It resulted in an improvement (1700ms) but not a huge one and I would lose the improvement (and then some) on the inserts.  The list of IDs is dynamic / chosen by the user based on filters they are setting - so I can't populate such a table in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that a large portion of the time is actually being spent in the 'group by' clause?

Have a look at the execution plan to see.

I wonder if increasing the list of person IDs is actually causing the DateKey sort cost to increase linearly. If so, add an index on the DateKey column.